# Div part is not shown with google map

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I want to add google map in the page. The page has a picture and some profile information, it was shown well. But, after adding google map, I cannot see the item-detail part, it only show item-profile and the google map. Could you please check what is wrong??

My html file is as below:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="item-profile" text-center #profilePic [style.background-image]="'url(' + item.profilepic + ')'">
  </div>

  <div class="item-detail" padding>
    <h2>ID: {{item.email}}</h2>
    <p>About: {{item.about}}</p>
  </div>

  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

My scss file is as:

```
page-item-detail {
  .item-profile {
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 250px;
  }

  .item-detail {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
  }

  #map{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: After removing item-detail's position setting in scss file, it shows.

Comment: did you tried z-index ? 
set z-index: 9999 for item-detail and see what gonna happen